# как поместить консольное приложение на хостинг

Tags: c#, .net, хостинг

Сорри за оффтоп, подскажите всю процедуру публикации готового консольного приложения на хостинг, в инете нашёл  только про asp.net который мне не нужен, и на ютубе тоже ничего толкового

Comment: а зачем? как пользователь будет получать к нему доступ, через браузер, тогда зачем консольное? или вы планируете предоставлять доступ всем к консоли сервера (т.е. не только к приложению, но и другим частям системы)?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten у меня дискорд бот

Comment: [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice). Публикуется точно так же, как и любое другое веб-приложение на .NET. Шаблон проекта в Visual Studio - Worker Service

Comment: Тут все зависит от места, куда вы хотите разместить проект. Если это хостинг, то некоторые поддерживают только Web проекты, а некоторые позволяют развернуть многое (например Azure). Вы можете арендовать VDS/VPS и там уже будет полноценная OS, на которой вы можете поставить все, что вашей душе угодно также, как и на вашем домашнем компьютере. А можете пойти по пути Heroku, который тоже позволяет разместить там проект, но только официальной поддержки C# там нет, но есть способы публикации через Docker. Как видите вариантов много и все они разные, выбирайте что-то одно и пробуйте.